# How to display mysql table row values

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to display row 0 and row 1 values in to text field.this is my code.but it's display "Undefined offset: 1 in C:\wamp\www\member\sys-admin\groups.php on line 15 ,Undefined offset: 2 in C:\wamp\www\member\sys-admin\groups.php on line 16 ,Undefined offset: 3 in C:\wamp\www\member\sys-admin\groups.php on line 17".

```
  <?php
        $r_sql = "SELECT ugroup FROM ugroups ";
        $r_result = db::getInstance()->query($r_sql);
        $row = $r_result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

             $g1 = $row['0'];
             $g2 = $row[1];
             $g3 = $row[2];
             $g4 = $row[3];
    ?>
```

html

```
<input name="g1" type="text" id="g1" style="width:300px;" value="<?php echo $g1;  ?>" />
<input name="g2" type="text" id="g2" style="width:300px;" value="<?php echo $g2;  ?>" />
```

[image: ugroups table]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're only accessing one row from the query with your call `$row = $r_result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)`. Also, `PDO::FETCH NUM` will return the array index by column number which is why `$row[1]` doesn't work (you only have one column in your query).

You'll want to use something like `$row = $r_result->fetchAll()` to retrieve ALL of the rows from your query and then you should be able to access them using `$row[0]['ugroup'], $row[1]['ugroup']` or, even better, from within a loop: `while ($row = $r_result->fetch())` etc.